# jquery dblclick on a page show error BodyContent_ondblclick() is not defined

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In a jquery page when user dblclick it is throwing

Error jScript:'BodyContent_ondblclik' is not defined, and stop at this code. Script block [Dynamic]

```
function ondblclick(event)
{
  return BodyContent_ondblclick()
}
```

My app is:
mobile Asp.net MVC4.

jquery 1.8.2

jquery mobile 1.2.0

How can I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: did u define BodyContent_ondblclick method??

Comment: no. I' never defined on my code it.

Comment: then how will it run??...define a function named BodyContent_ondblclick or remove that line...

Comment: I found it on a template generated on a prior versión of Mvc, now it removed, tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define a function named BodyContent_ondblclick or remove that line